# Spring Mail. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: jakarta-mail

I connect to mail server on protocol smtp on port without encryption.
I get error

```
"Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;\n  nested exception is:\n\tjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;\n  nested exception is:\n\tjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake"
```

My bean's config

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSender.setHost(host);
    javaMailSender.setProtocol(protocol);
    javaMailSender.setUsername(from);
    javaMailSender.setPassword(password);
    javaMailSender.setPort(port);
    javaMailSender.setDefaultEncoding(encoding);
    Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "127.0.0.1");
    javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
    javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);

    return javaMailSender;
}
```

I can say one before it worked. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a disagreement about which TLS versions or cipher suites are supported by both client and server.  If you upgraded the JDK, for example, that might've changed.  The `https.protocols` property isn't used by JavaMail, but if you need to set that for other reasons you may need to set the corresponding JavaMail property, e.g., [`mail.smtp.ssl.protocols`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.protocols).

You might need to follow the debugging tips in [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) to find out exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");